# Do I still need a web application framework if I have ORM already done?

Tags: java, grails, frameworks

I'm starting my research on web application frameworks and according to what I've read, web application frameworks provide ORM and basic UI's through scaffolding.  But I had ORM already done.  What other benefits do frameworks provide? do I still need one?  or in case not,  What other technologies could I use?

I'm working on Java and was considering Grails and GWT.  Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the framework you choose, they can provide a number of other benefits in addition to data access:

- Simplified URL configuration
- Templating system for page content
- Security (authentication and/or authorization)
- Methods to streamline Ajax requests/responses
- Use of conventions to reduce/eliminate ugly XML configuration
- Caching mechanisms

Some frameworks provide most all of these things in addition to data access -- Grails, Rails, Django and CakePHP come to mind.  Others are primarily concerned with view and controller logic, and do not include a specialized data access component -- GWT, Struts, Spring MVC and Wicket, among many others.

But do you need a framework?  It really depends on the scope and constraints of your project.  If a framework can eliminate the need for you to custom-develop a few of the items listed above, and you have the time to pick it up and gain the productivity offered, I say go for it.

I'll also say that many jobs prefer or flat-out require experience in certain frameworks.  Gaining at least a fundamental knowledge of more frameworks is always a good thing, opporutinistically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a web front end on your existing persistence tier if you've got it done.